# Load Balancing with the WSHttp Binding: Do not use reliable sessions? WHY?

Tags: wcf, load, load-balancing

We have WCF service X: deployed on server A and Server B, host address:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8777/ServiceX/
```

And we load balance the two servers. We accesss the service via `http://myappserver/ServiceX`

We need to use per-session mode, and we set [reliable sessions] as true:

We don't find any issue till now based on testing. But the below linked MSDN article says that Do not use reliable sessions for Load Balancing with the WSHttp Binding? Please can someone give more details? Thanks a lot.

[WCF Load Balancing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx)

Comment: Are we applying/using load balancing to wsHttp Binding WCF service correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Reliable Messaging means all your messages from your established client reach the same endpoint behind any intermediaries like routers and load balancers.

Load balancing means your calls will be distributed across all nodes as the load balancer sees fit.

Those two goals are mutually exclusive. You can have one or the other, not both.

Comment: I don't think so. See [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20090302072037/http://daveonsoftware.blogspot.com/2007/08/load-balancer-persistence-sticky.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have not had time to try this myself yet, but I found this old blog entry (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/drnick/2007/07/13/sticky-sessions/):

> This division according to groups would allow a feature like reliable messaging to work because the same server would be used to process all of the messages in the reliable session. The feature that this division method represents is typically called “sticky sessions” or some other phrase for affinitization in the load balancer.

Given that you mention that your firewall supports sticky sessions, I suspect/hope you will be fine.